# How to submit user feedback using Sentry api in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sentry, user-feedback

I've setup Sentry and got it automatically reporting exceptions, however I haven't managed to get user feedback submission working.

The python script is CLI based, so I would like the user to be able to type the bug information straight into the command line window, instead of generating a webpage and using that, as through the CLI is more seemless in my use case.

The code below was my attempt to follow the [Sentry user feedback submission API Python documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/api/projects/submit-user-feedback/)

The `bearer_auth_token` was obtained by following the Sentry auth API documentation

Example bare-bones code:

```
organisation_slug = 'cooldev'
project_slug = 'python-app'
bearer_auth_token = 'dcb275d6aaa040e1818326bec567cb0d9c09343171c65451ab53e740fa450314'  # with scope project:write
dsn_link = 'https://8ef42a3641fa42d69fdf8e034732a3c5@o357469.ingest.sentry.io/4423355'

import sentry_sdk, requests

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=dsn_link,
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
    environment='testing'
)

def bug_send(event_id, name, email, comments):
    url = f'https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/{organisation_slug}/{project_slug}/user-feedback/'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearer_auth_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    data = {
        "event_id": str(event_id),
        "name": str(name),
        "email": str(email),
        "comments": str(comments)}

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=str(data))
    return response


try:
    x = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    event_id = sentry_sdk.last_event_id()
    name = input('Name: ')
    email = input('Email: ')
    comments = input('Comments: ')
    response = bug_send(event_id, name, email, comments)
    print(response.status_code, response.reason)
    input()
```

Output:

```
Name: John Doe
Email: john.doe@gmail.com
Comments: It is not working!
400 Bad Request
```

Comment: `data=str(data)` is the wrong way to go about this. Use `json=data` and yeah, get rid of the content-type header. But that question is more about requests usage than anything else.

Comment: This was a rough code example, the current code I'm using does use `payload=data` instead. I had no idea what was causing the bad request as I haven't made post requests before and followed the documentation example.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `Content-Type` header did the trick. The new response was `200 OK`, and I could see the feedback shown up in Sentry

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same confusing error (400 with no body) and realised after a while that the issue was caused by me using the slug from one project and the DSN of another.